# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException - /res/color/file.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, android-resources, android-color

I'm trying to implement the **Color State List Resources** in my android application, following Android developer guide [Color State List Resource | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html). So I created two resource files `button_text.xml` and `button_background.xml` in the directory `res/color/` and referred them in the with `@color/button_text` and `@color/button_background` respectively in the `activity_main.xml`. Here's the **layout code**:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/button_text"
    android:background="@color/button_background"/>
```

On running the App, I'm getting a `Resources Not Found Exception` in the logs as shown below:

```
Process: com.example.myanimation, PID: 29254
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myanimation/com.example.myanimation.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class Button
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class Button
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class Button
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.example.myanimation:color/button_background with resource ID #0x7f0b0053
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/button_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0b0053
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:729)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:575)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:854)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4177)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:710)
at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:109)
at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:105)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:65)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:61)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1026)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1083)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
at com.example.myanimation.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

I've tried to clean and rebuild the project but it didn't work. Also, putting the `xml files` in `res/drawable/` instead of `res/color/` is showing the same error.Please help solving the issue. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Here is the `button_text.xml` file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#000"
          android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:color="#fff"
          android:state_activated="true"/>
</selector>
```

And, `button_background.xml` file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#fff"
          android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:color="#000"
          android:state_activated="true"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: paster your  android:textColor="@color/button_text"
    android:background="@color/button_background" files

Comment: have you set color like `<color name="button_text">#272c33</color>` in you `xml` file

Comment: @Akshay I've added the `color/button_text.xml` and `color/button_background.xml` code in the question @NileshRathod

Comment: Just to be safe, you have double checked the name of the file button_background.xml?

Comment: Affirmative. @j.e.gr

Comment: @j.e.gr I checked it. The file name `button_background.xm` is correct. I've posted the answer, please check.

Comment: @Robin check my ans

Comment: @Robin did your problrm solved

Comment: Yes @Nilesh Rathod

Comment: thna please mark my ans as correct thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, here it is. Please read the full answer. The `android:background` attribute does not supports the `Color State List` unlike `android:textColor`. To make `android:background` property work, you need `State List Drawables`. Thus, instead of `res/color/` create the file in `res/drawable/` directory. Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/white"
          android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/black"
          android:state_activated="true"/>
</selector>
```

Note the use of android:drawable instead of android:color. Android will use the color resource and make a drawable out of it. To finish this off, you need to add the color resources to your res/values/colors.xml file.

For More information : [CLICK HERE!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18131705/7038650)

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

Change

```
android:background="@color/button_background"
```

To

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/button_background"
```

The above code work fine, if your button_background.xml file put in `res/color/`

Answer (score 0):

try this it will help you
**follow this**

**Step 1:-> create a button_text.xml in res/color/ directory.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item  android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
<item  android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
<item  android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
</selector>
```

Step 2 :-> create a button_selector.xml in res/drawble/ directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item  android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/disha"/>
<item  android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/back"/>
<item  android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_edit_pen"/>
</selector>
```

**Step3 :- now appy in your button**

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/button_text"
    android:background="@drawable/button_selector" />
```

**aks me in case of any query**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `button_text.xml` file is working fine but `button_background.xml` wasn't. Check my answer

Comment: in button_background you have to create your custom drawable shapes for buttons

Answer (score 0):

If you look better the stack trace exception you should find this:

```
 Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
```

You can find the solution here:
[Error : <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114322/error-item-tag-requires-a-drawable-attribute-or-child-tag-defining-a-drawa?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score -1):

Firstly you have to shift your `button_text.xml` and `button_background.xml` to `drawable` directory.

then set like:

```
android:textColor="@drawable/button_text"
android:background="@drawable/button_background"
```

Comment: That didn't work but thanks! Moreover, I've provided a link in my Question to the Official Android Developer Guide which says that, we should create the `selector's xml` file in the `res/color/` directory.