# Colorstatelist for button background not working

Tags: android, button, colors

Reference: [How to specify background color in Color State List Resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953606/how-to-specify-background-color-in-color-state-list-resources)

I have followed the popular answer in the link above.

I have the following drawable;

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@color/KeyActionPrimary"/> <!-- enabled -->
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@color/KeyActionButtonDeactivated"/> <!-- disabled -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/KeyActionPrimary"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@color/KeyActionPrimary"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/KeyActionPrimary"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

I understand that it will always follow order of precedence and therefore in the current order only activated and deactivated likely to be triggered. Currently however I am not getting any results at all

My button;

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSTART"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_height"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/state_controlled_key_action_button"
        android:padding="@dimen/btn_padding"
        android:text="@string/btn_start"
        android:textColor="@color/key_action_button_text_color"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnSCORES"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

The button comes out as white which in my material theme is the ColorPrimary attribute

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Home" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/Primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/PrimaryVariant</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/Secondary</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/SecondaryVariant</item>
        <!--colorBackground appears behind scrollable content and is used for the default window-->
        <!--background. colorSurface is mapped to the surface of components such as cards, sheets-->
        <!--and menus. colorError is used to indicate an error state for components such as-->
        <!--text fields.-->
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/Background</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/Surface</item>
        <item name="colorError">@color/Error</item>
        <!--"On" colors define how text, icons and strokes are colored in relation to the surface-->
        <!--on which they appear.-->
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/ColorOnPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/ColorOnSecondary</item>
        <item name="colorOnBackground">@color/ColorOnBackground</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/ColorOnSurface</item>
        <item name="colorOnError">@color/ColorOnError</item>

        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/atma_medium</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/PrimaryTextColor</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@color/StatusBar</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

        <item name="actionBarSize">36dip</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Firstly I am assuming that a theme covers the entire app but if you explicitly specify a background to a specific button it should override the theme value, please correct me if I am wrong.

I started this journey with a colorstatelist under res/colors. Read the link at the top which confirmed you need to use drawable. As I already had a color state list initially followed the advice of the answer which had 0 votes...

shape

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@color/primary_button_color" />
    <stroke android:width="@dimen/btn_stroke" android:color="@color/primary_button_stroke_color"/>
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/btn_radius"/>
</shape>
```

colorstatelist

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:color="@color/Primary"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:color="@color/PrimaryButtonDeactivated"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="@color/Primary"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:color="@color/Primary"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="@color/Primary"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Neither of these approaches is amending my button color. I am still always seeing a white button. I purposely chose horrid colors to ensure the change was obvious

What am I doing wrong? What else do you need to see?

UPDATE...........

Following discussion with @rcs I used my original colorstatelist from res/color with the backgroundtint property on the button and it works as intended

My final code:

For each button that requires a different style i have a button color or text color file in res/colors as per below

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="@color/KeyActionColorOnPrimary"/>
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:color="@color/KeyActionPrimary"/>
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:color="@color/lime"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:color="@color/KeyActionPrimary"/>
    <item android:color="@color/KeyActionPrimary"/>
</selector>
```

Then within my button xml

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/key_action_button_color" // for button color
android:textColor="@color/key_action_button_text_color" // for text color
```

e.g.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSTART"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_height"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/key_action_button_color"
        android:padding="@dimen/btn_padding"
        android:text="@string/btn_start"
        android:textColor="@color/key_action_button_text_color"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnSCORES"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

This works with no additional styles. I can keep my material design theme without the button style being set to apt compat style. I am only using the above attributes in the layout xml for the button i want to have these styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the first condition in your `color_state` is `android:state_enabled="true", which is always the case, thereby resulting in the same color. Get rid of it to notice the color changes

Refer the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList) for more info and try to use a `color` file resource instead of `drawable` as the docs says,

> ColorStateLists are created from XML resource files defined in the "color" subdirectory directory of an application's resource directory

Edit:

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53071828/why-doesnt-setenabledfalse-trigger-a-colorstatelist-for-theme-theme-appcompat) answer, applying the colorstate as a style to the `Button` tag should solve the issue

create a new style

```
    <style name="AppTheme.CustomButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/state_controlled_key_action_button</item>
    </style>
```

**Activity**

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/your_button_id"
        style="@style/AppTheme.CustomButtonStyle"/>
```

Comment: Sometimes I disable the buttons. And it is not applying the enabled color as stated in my problem where I say it's still applying the theme color so that doesn't sound right @rcs

Comment: what do you mean by`Sometimes I disable the buttons And it is not applying the enabled color` because, if the button is disabled then `<item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:color="@color/PrimaryButtonDeactivated"/>`gets registered and that's exactly what I am seeing on my device

Comment: The colour set to all states apart from disabled is orange. The button where this is set as background is still white and it is currently enabled so should be orange not white

Comment: I have just tried this instead. Which has pressed first as red, enabled as orange and disabled as green. My button is still white in all cases. selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="@color/KeyActionColorOnPrimary"/>
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:color="@color/KeyActionPrimary"/>
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:color="@color/lime"/>
</selector>

Comment: `primarycolor` is preponderating, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53071828/why-doesnt-setenabledfalse-trigger-a-colorstatelist-for-theme-theme-appcompat) for how to deal with it

Comment: thanks RCS although I am a little confused reading it as it talks directly to appcompat theme and the only mention of material theme is text color which works fine for me? or is it suggesting buttons have to be an appcompat style and not material in order to change color states?

Comment: It suggests the buttons having an appcompat style for noticing the colorstatelist, tried it out on my device and its working as expected

Comment: I must sound really stupid but i amended style to @style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored and it made no difference. It really should not be this hard just to set a color state list for buttons. I have three types of button as well so need to vary styles (key call to action button, secondary buttons like info etc and then game buttons (like ones with answers on)

Comment: as a last resort, make sure the color_state_list is a color file and not drawable and use backgroundtint and if ur problem still prevails, will look up for more resources/docs

Comment: I will try that shortly as I have color state lists in res/color as thats how i started but I was not using it against the tint. I will advise results once back at my laptop. thanks for staying with me on this problem

Comment: that option works well actually and i dont need the style changed to app compat either. All i had to do was take my color state list from res/color and apply it to tint. That was it.