# How to change color of ListView items on focus and on click

Tags: android, listview, background-color, listviewitem

i have a list View in my app (this is the xml layout):

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/arrayList"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:textFilterEnabled="true"
       android:scrollbars="vertical"
       android:drawSelectorOnTop="true">
</ListView>
```

Each item of my list View is composed of two TextView:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/row_container"
       android:padding="5px" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@color/white" android:shrinkColumns="0">
               <TableRow>
               <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/
description"
                       android:id="@+id/description"
                       android:textColor="@color/black"
                       android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                       android:singleLine="true"></TextView>
       </TableRow>
       <TableRow>
               <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/result"
                       android:textColor="@color/grey"
                       android:maxLines="1"
                       android:scrollHorizontally="true"></TextView>
       </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

I'm populating my listView from an ArrayAdapter, in this way:

```
public class Matches extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    //set layout

    setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);
  // obtain reference to listview
  ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.arrayList);

  ArrayAdapter<Match> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Match>(
        this, R.layout.custom_row, R.id.description, createItems()) {

     @Override
     public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        Match item = getItem (position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, null);
        TextView description = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        TextView result = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.result);
        description.setText(item.description + "  Risultato: " + item.result );
        result.setText(item.date + "  " + item.hour);
        return rowView;
     }
  };

  listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

My goal is to be able to change the text color and the backgorund of these child views whenever the parent is selected or pressed.

How can i do it?

Comment: How would you set focus without the user clicking?

Answer (score 38):

The child views in your list row should be considered selected whenever the parent row is selected, so you should be able to just set a normal state drawable/color-list on the views you want to change, no messy Java code necessary. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506319/android-linearlayout-with-color-resource-what-am-i-doing-wrong).

Specifically, you'd set the `textColor` of your textViews to an XML resource like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/black" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/black" /> <!-- focused and pressed-->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/green" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/black" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Comment: Hey Yoni, what does `setItemsCanFocus(boolean)` mean?

Answer (score 33):

In your ***main.xml*** include the following in your ListView:

```
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"

android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray"
```

Comment: The focused list cell stays highlighted after releasing the touch, if you do it this way.

Answer (score 5):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >    
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/YOUR DRAWABLE XML" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/YOUR DRAWABLE XML" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Hey Dhiral, what does `setItemsCanFocus(boolean)` mean?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a [good article](http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2009/12/android-selectors.html) on how to use selectors with lists.

Instead of setting it to be the android:background of the ListView, I believe you want to set android:listSelector as shown below:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:divider="@null" 
  android:dividerHeight="0dip"
  android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                final int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.listlongclick_selection));

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sir Many Places Create Null Pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

Very old but I have just struggled with this, this is how I solved it in pure xml.  In *res/values/colors.xml* I added three colours (the *colour_...*);

```
<resources>

    <color name="black_overlay">#66000000</color>

    <color name="colour_highlight_grey">#ff666666</color>
    <color name="colour_dark_blue">#ff000066</color>
    <color name="colour_dark_green">#ff006600</color>

</resources>
```

In the *res/drawable* folder I created *listview_colours.xml* which contained;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colour_highlight_grey" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colour_dark_blue" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colour_dark_green" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colour_dark_blue" android:state_focused="true"/>
</selector>
```

In the *main_activity.xml* find the List View and add the drawable to *listSelector*;

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/menuList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_colours"
    android:background="#ff222222"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Play with the *state_...* items in the *listview_colours.xml* to get the effect you want.

There is also a method where you can set the style of the List View but I never managed to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Declare list item components as final outside your setOnClickListener or whatever you want to apply on your list item like this:

```
final View yourView;
final TextView yourTextView;
```

And in overriding onClick or whatever method you use, just set colors as needed like this:

```
yourView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE/*or whatever RGB suites good contrast*/);
yourTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK/*or whatever RGB suites good contrast*/);
```

Or without the final declaration, if let's say you implement an onClick() for a custom adapter to populate a list, this is what I used in getView() for my setOnClickListener/onClick():

```
//reset color for all list items in case any item was previously selected
for(int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++)
{
  parent.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
  TextView text=(TextView) parent.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.item);
  text.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0,178,178));
}
//highlight currently selected item
 parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0,178,178));
 TextView text=(TextView) parent.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.item);
 text.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0,178,178));
```