# how to change color of android list item on click or selection?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change color of ListView items on focus and on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247385/how-to-change-color-of-listview-items-on-focus-and-on-click)

friends,

i want to change color on android list item click 
any one guide me which attribute should i use to achieve this functionality?

actually when user clicks on list item he does not know if it was clicked or not?

here is my code.

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Tablayoutdesign"
        android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="63dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dip"
        />
```

Comment: i had edited, my answer, please refer it

Comment: hi Umar i am also facing same problem as was your..how u overcome from this problem pls would u share me?pls

Answer (score 27):

Step1: Embbed the android:listSelector attribute in your ListView as Shown Below.

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/Tablayoutdesign"
        android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="63dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dip"

        />
```

Step2: Create a new xml named listselector and put the following code in that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 

  <!-- Selected --> 
  <item 
    android:state_focused="true" 
    android:state_selected="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/focused"/> 

  <!-- Pressed -->
  <item 
    android:state_selected="true" 
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/selected" /> 

</selector>
```

Step3: Create a file named colors.xml
add the following the code in that file

```
<resources>
    <drawable name="focused">#ff5500</drawable>
    <drawable name="selected">#FF00FF</drawable>
</resources>
```

Add this line in your java code

```
ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
lv.setSelector( R.drawable.listselector);
```

Comment: @UMMA: Is your problem solved, did you reached your destination?

Comment: @UMMA: pls tell, what error you had got?, can you resuse again, i had mistaken that  android:drawable=" android:drawable=@drawable/focused", now i edited, pls check the edited answer

Comment: on focus behaving here like cacheHintColor.pressed is not working..no color change on pressed :(

Comment: @UMMA: did you created listselector.xml file in drawable folder

Comment: changed two properties in list android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" and android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" added file in drawable folder with selector data and resources... still i think it has no change on my item click color :(

Comment: @UMMA: create list_selector.xml file in drawable folder and create color.xml file under values folder

Comment: @UMMA: what problem still you are facing?

Comment: yaar no color change on list item click :( there is no error every thing is perfect as you told me.

Comment: @UMMA:Give me a couple of seconds, in the meanwhile i request you to clean your project and build it.

Comment: @UMMA: did you checked now???, still that same problem exists?

Comment: @UMMA: i had founded the problem, where you went wrong???

Comment: yes please tell me what mistake was it?

Comment: @UMMa: did your probelm is sloved?

Comment: @shankar ganesh i am also trying to do it but failure..nothing happen when i click on list at any position..pls can u help me?

Comment: This will change the background color for the list view not the list item since the selector is set to the listview

Comment: It hasn't worked for me too

Comment: Does not work for Lists in the Preference Screen :(

Comment: No result here neither.. Item stay white and no colors at all

Comment: What does @drawable/focused look like?

Comment: same thing here..not worked for me

Comment: not working for me :(

Comment: Another way around of lv.setSelector( R.drawable.listselector), you can also use android:listSelector="@drawable/listselector". looks cleaner ;)