# How to set background colour for listview selected item

Tags: android, listview

Working fine when we use selector. but this is temporary. if focus change of list item then selected color also change.  But i want different.  When we click on list view item then that particular item color change. After that we can move another items of list view. When we click another item. then again this particular selected item want to set color, and last colored list item release from color

Comment: I am using Android. Please help me about that.

Comment: Here is the [answer][1] for you question. It changes the color on selection


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365893/how-to-change-color-of-android-list-item-on-click-or-selection