# ListView setOnItemClickListener isn't working

Tags: android, listview, listener

Like the title says, my setOnItemClickListener isn't working. I looked through everything I've seen so far on SO and couldn't find my error.

This is the code:

This is the problematic class. It isn't the main class, but is called from an intent:

```
package...;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class GroupActivity extends Activity {

    String group_id = "";
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_group);
        context = this;

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        group_id = intent.getStringExtra("group_id");
        Log.i("bla", "Launched GroupActivity for group_id " + group_id);

        final SubAdapter adapter = new SubAdapter(this, group_id);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setClickable(true);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int idx, long lidx) {
                Log.i("print here", "blaa " + idx);

            }

        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is the SubAdapter class:

```
package...;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SubAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final int thumb_width = 128;
    private static final int thumb_hight = 128;
    private static Bitmap default_thumb = null;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private final String group_id_;
    private final Activity activity;
    private final SubAdapter t = this;

    // used to keep selected position in ListView
    private int selectedPos = -1;   // init value for not-selected

    public SubAdapter(Activity a, final String group_id) {
        Drawable d = a.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture);
        default_thumb = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
        activity = a;
        group_id_ = group_id;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int idx, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.i("bla2", "getting view with index " + idx);
        View vi = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_list_item, null);
            vi.setClickable(true);
        }
        TextView tv1 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        ImageView img = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        tv1.setText("first name" + " " + "last name");
        tv2.setText("some date");

        // put thumbnail
        Bitmap thumb = default_thumb;
        img.setImageBitmap(thumb);
        Log.i("bla3", "index is " + idx + "selected index is " + selectedPos);
        if(selectedPos == idx){
            Log.i("bla4", "inside if");
         }      
        return vi;
    }


    public void setSelectedPosition(int pos){
    selectedPos = pos;
         // inform the view of this change
         notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

This is the activity_group xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".GroupActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:focusable="false" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the sub_list_item xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="some text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:text="more text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:text="present" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Apart from the click listener, everything else seems to work. The SubAdapter opens properly and the list is populated. 
Basically what I'm looking for is to get the message "Log.i("print here", "blaa " + idx);" to print - it is the log from the ListView's setOnItemClickListener (look above)

Please let me know if there is any other relevant code missing
Thanks!!!

Comment: Try changing your log message to `Log.i("print here", "blaa " + idx.toString());` Also, I wouldn't rely completely on log messages for debugging like this. I would put a breakpoint and make sure it doesn't get called. Does it crash or does nothing?

Comment: I removed it completely, still nothing

Comment: Does nothing.
The rest of the log messages do print. Also, there is more code after the log that doesn't get done.

Comment: i think i once had a problem on some AndroidAPI when setting the listener first and then setting the Adapter worked better.

Comment: Simon, thanks. I tryed it now and it didn't help..

Comment: remove  android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:focusable="false"

Comment: you have a toogle button in it. the on item click listener stops working when the items can be focused, you need to focusableintouchmode as false for the buttoon

Comment: Check my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535996/listview-item-is-not-clickable-please-give-some-hint/16536355#16536355

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot later today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably remove the call to 
`vi.setClickable(true);` in your SubAdapter class, because your convertView will consume the click before you onItemClick listener.

Comment: It wasnt originally there, I put it there as part of trying to find a solution...

Comment: Ok same for android:clickable, android:focusable, and android:focusableintouchmode in listview in the xml layout. Remove it!

Comment: All working now, I missed one of the setClickable() earlier. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

In your GroupActivity class please add the following code before findViewById method:

now you get the view same and change your code

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

to

```
final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rescuer_no_dialog, null);
ListView lv = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

`ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);`

to

`lv = getListView()`

Extend `ListActivity` and declare lv outside methods.