# Items in Listview is not clickable android

Tags: android

I manages to to create a activity with dialog theme and add listview with custom ArrayAdapter for using different icons.

Now the problem is ,the items in the listview are not clickable....pls help me to solve this

contact_info_more_options.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:divider="#00CCFF"
        android:dividerHeight="0.2dp">
    </ListView>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"             
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="0.0dip" 
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"                       
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

list_more_options.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:padding="5dip">

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/karthik" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"

        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtvw_option"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/list_image"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_image"
    android:text="Save as note"
    android:textColor="#181818"
    android:textSize="20dip" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

ContactInfoMoreOption.java

```
public class ContactInfoMoreOption extends ListActivity{
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
     String[] moreOptions ={ "Save as note", "Call", "SMS", "Send E-Mail"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact_info_more_options);
        getListView().setAdapter(new IconicAdapter());  
        StateListDrawable state=new StateListDrawable();
        state.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradinet_hover));
        state.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected}, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradinet_hover));    
        getListView().setBackgroundDrawable(state);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        //get selected items
        String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
    class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
        IconicAdapter() {
          super(ContactInfoMoreOption.this, R.layout.list_more_options, moreOptions);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {
          LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
          View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_more_options, parent, false);
          TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtvw_option);

          label.setText(moreOptions[position]);

          ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.list_image);

          if (label.getText().equals("Save as note")) {
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.note);
        }
          else if (label.getText().equals("Call")) {
              icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.call);
        }
          else if (label.getText().equals("SMS")) {
              icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.sms);
            }
          else {
              icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.mail);
            }

          return(row);
        }
      }

}
```

Comment: try this String selectedValue = (String) l.getItemAtPosition(position);

Comment: Try setting `android:clickable="true"` for ListView in your XML. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:clickable

Comment: Can u help me to change background of list item when clicked ...I tried this too,but didn't worked

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
l.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

instead of

```
getListAdapter().getItem(position);
```

Comment: thanks it worked.... Can u help me to change background of list item when clicked ...I tries this too,but didn't worked

Comment: For changing background color on click see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365893/how-to-change-color-of-android-list-item-on-click-or-selection) question.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this. Replace:

```
String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
```

With:

```
String selectedValue = (String) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

//do sth.
```

}
});