# How are listitems being darkened when touched in "Bluetooth Le Gatt" sample project provided by Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, touch-event

Looking through stackoverflow, I've found answers as to how to darken a listitem when its being touched so that the user knows which item in the list view is about to be selected.

[How to change color of ListView items on focus and on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247385/how-to-change-color-of-listview-items-on-focus-and-on-click).

But I cannot find any sort of implementation for that type of function in the Bluetooth Le Gatt sample project provided by Android Studios.

Comment: Presumably you're trying to implement something similar to this on your own. Why don't you try to write some code first and come back with a question if you are having a specific issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I gave my listitems backgrounds which change their colour from the regular white using an xml file in my drawable folder. This prevented the list item from darkening when touching it.

edit: you can also set your background as selectable to give it an effect when selected/pressed.

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```