# Custom ListView not highlighting ListViewItem on click

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, listviewitem

I have a custom listview made up of an ImageView and a TextView. Clicking works fine however it won't highlight the item like a normal ListView would. How would I add a highlight? I tried to rig it by setting the background color on click and then adding a timer to remove the background color. That worked but I want a better solution. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you create your custom ListView?  You are probably doing something wrong if that is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can try to use the [colorstate](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html). Define the colors for state_pressed, state_selected and any other appropriate states, then set the background of your view to the colorstate.

Comment: Hey be aware that setting the background should use DRAWABLE resource but not COLOR resource. look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3507264/1099884)

Answer (score 5):

Click on your ListView and then in the properties window, set drawSelectorOnTop to true. I just had the same issue and that worked like a charm.

Comment: Definitely the easiest answer. Works perfectly!