# Custom List view not highlighting on clicking list view item

Tags: android, android-listview

I needed to use custom title bar so I changed the manifest and created my custom theme. Till here every thing was fine, but same activity was having a list view, so I used custom list view and changed accordingly. Every thing went fine, **But on click of any item in list view, item was not getting highlighted**.
I went through various links but not found the solution. I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621675/custom-listview-not-highlighting-listviewitem-on-click) link which has similar problem but solution is not working in my case. If any body could help.

**My attempt:** My list_bg.xml is

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
    android:drawable="@color/grey" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@color/blue" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@color/blue" />
</selector>
```

I have added the above code in color folder and gave the reference as `android:background="@color/list_bg"` in list view item xml.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Did you inflate the list items with a custom adapter? If you set a background for the list item xml, the list highlight doesn't work.

Comment: I didn't ge you. What do you mean by `inflate`

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
<item 
android:drawable="@color/grey" />
```

at the end of your XML. The state list is traversed top to bottom and the first item that matches the current state is used

Comment: thanks for reply sir but no, its not help full. still its like static list

Comment: What do you mean by "static list"? Does you list get highlighted by "standard" `ListView` style?

Comment: no, its not getting highlight, that's my problem and question. Its like onItemClickListner is not working

Comment: Are your items enabled? Do you override `isEnabled()` or `areAllItemsEnabled()` and returning `false`?

Comment: no, I am not overriding such functions. I just created a list view and custom theme. and my list view was not showing default behaviour

Comment: it seems like attribute from list_bg is in background because default color is not shown in front list but it shown somewhat faded  at background on right portion where list is ending

Comment: Try adding `android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"` to your `ListView` XML definition

Comment: No still the same result, I mean no result.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10175/discussion-between-207-and-black-devil)

Answer (score 0):

android:listSelector="#000000"

use this attribute in listview.