# How to change backgroundcolor of clicked row in a single choice listview

Tags: android, listview

I want to create a single choice listview in which when an item is pressed i should be able to change the background color of the item pressed. I have tried setting the backgroundcolor of the view parameter passed to the *onItemClick* function but this changes the backgrouncolor of someother item. After the background color change i want to make the Listview non clickable. I have tried setting *clickable* and *focusable* to false in the *onItemClick* handler function but that doesnt help. I also want to be able to populate this ListView with new data and then make it *clickable* again later. I will have only four listviewitems so is it better not to use the listview at all and may be use four buttons.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [a stateful drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList). See [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3506319/272824) for more details.