# Selector color on LinearLayout

Tags: android, colors, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to assing a color selector to an extended class of LinearLayout, so, i think its like if we speak about linearLayout.

i followed the instructions on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506319/android-linearlayout-with-color-resource-what-am-i-doing-wrong) post, the answer talking about shapes.

Now i have 3 xml on drawables folders:

normal.xml file

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle" >
  <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
</shape>
```

pressed.xml file

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#00000000" />
</shape>
```

and finally, bg.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
</selector>
```

I am accessing this in the following way:

```
    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(context.getResources().getIdentifier("mypackageuri.tProject:drawable/bg", null, null));
    view.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

The "normal" state its fine, with the color set at "normal.xml", but no way with the other ones, I press my view and nothing happens, it's not changing color in any way...

I can't see what i'm doing wrong...

Thank you

Comment: might want to paste your layout xml

Comment: Whoa that has to be the most roundabout way of getting a drawable resource. Instead of 
  
`getResources().getDrawable(context.getResources().getIdentifier("mypackageuri.tProject:drawable/bg", null, null));`     

try 

`getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg);` . Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @dmon good point, ill try that too! thanks!!

Comment: if somebody wants to get full solution, check this repository: https://github.com/shamanland/AndroidLayoutSelector there is custom clickable/checkable ```LinearLayout``` like a ```ToggleButton```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your view needs to be clickable in order to get the state `pressed` when you click on it.
Use :

```
    view.setClickable(true);
```

or in the layout xml :

```
    android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: something as simple as that... thank you!! i'll try it tomorrow!