# android linearlayout background selector

Tags: android, selector, inflate

I am adding some Linearlayout views in a scrollview by inflating them dynamically. I have set the background of the added LinearLayout to a selector list. But after adding to scrollview, when I press the selected view, it does not show any affect of selector list. The example XMLs I am using are:

Selector file:    selector_file

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/listbg"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bgsmall"/>
</selector>
```

And I am inflating the following view and adding to l1 Linearlayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/selector_file"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image1" android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="75dip"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/textitem" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the ScrollView to which the above inflated views are being added is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/l1"  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any Idea...???

Comment: does it work if you put it outside the scrollview?

Comment: I guess some controls in scrollview consumes pressed event so your child LinearLayout cannot get touch.

Comment: Actually I am setting the selector to the background of a Linearlayout. If I use the same selector for a button, it works but not for LinearLayout...

Comment: Thanks to all. I have got the solution. I have added the following lines in the Linearlayout of the inflated file:
    
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

Comment: android:clickable="true" fixes the problem of the button not looking pressed when it's pressed. But if you're using setSelected(true) then state_selected drawable doesn't work anymore...

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865730/selector-color-on-linearlayout

Answer (score 32):

You must make the *LinearLayout* clickable.

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: When I click one layout, all layouts show state pressed. This solve that issue too. Thanks!