# Using resources referenced in the current theme

Tags: android, styling

I find myself again trying to use resources set in the current theme inside my Android application and running into difficulties.

Following the rough guidelines found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes) for theme attribute value reuse

I was originally trying to create a selector like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

where the pressed state drawable is declared like so

```
<item name="selectableItemBackground">@android:drawable/item_background</item>
```

in the current ICS themes xml doc [themes xml doc](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml) . This compiles fine in eclispse (whereas if i spell the attr wrong it will give an error or reffng @android:drawable/item_background directly will inform me the drawable itself is private).

When i run the app i get a

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E / AndroidRuntime (18815): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

without any other useful information apart from the xml file that is using this selector for an `ImageViews android:background` attribute value. I know that there is a bug where colorStateLists cant be used as backgrounds [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506319/android-linearlayout-with-color-resource-what-am-i-doing-wrong) and maybe this also applys to drawableState lists referencing drawables from the theme. I know however it does work as the post mentioned describes.

Am i missing something here?? I always run into something i dont understand when trying to do stuff like this so would be glad of any pointers.

Thanks for any help

**EDIT**

as another experiement I tried setting an alias to the referenced drawable in the theme like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" ></bitmap>
```

and using this as the background directly but this does not work either. Looking at aliases they are onlyment to ref actual images so this makes sense

**EDIT 2**

another test an I have found using it directly

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

does actually work. So it seems that using it inside a alias or selector is where it gets unhappy. Strange as i would assume that both background and the same arg

**EDIT 3**

It seems the theme attr i was pointing at was actually a selector instelf, which im sure didnt help the issue! Thought i wouldve guessed looking at the name of it

Answer (score 1):

I guess i answered the question myself in my edits - main issue i imagine was that i was trying to ref a selector inside a selector.